# How to save an NSValue to disk?

Tags: cocoa-touch, ios, core-graphics

Say I have an NSValue object. How can I save this to disk and retrieve it later?

Eric

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`NSValue`s can't be saved in a `plist`, which is what `writeToFile` does. You can use archiving instead:

Save:
`[NSKeyedArchiver archiveRootObject: myNSValue toFile:@"myPath"];`

Load:
`NSValue *myNSValue = [NSKeyedUnarchiver unarchiveObjectWithFile:@"myPath"];`